# Combine TabLayout with BottomNavigationView - support.design library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, bottomnavigationview

according to the Android support.design library 25, I try to accomplish the combining use of both. [image: TabLayout with BottomNavigationView]

Before that, I used BottomNavigationView  with FrameLayout in the .XML Design, to load the fragments with transactionManager. The pages of TabsLayout should be loaded over ViewPager.

Now my question: When I use BottomNavigationView and TabsLayout together, should I load both pages over ViewPager?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem.

**Here is the working plan:**
1) Load Page over FrameLayout in .XML and FragmentManager (BottomNavigationView)

2) Create a Fragment-Container with the tabs

3) Load over this fragment-Container your Pages over ViewPager

4) Because of the Fragment-Container, I avoid to place TabLayout on each fragment-layout, and I avoid implementing ObTabSelectedListner on each TabFragment by achiving this in fragment-Container once

5) With this approach I didn't violate googles design rules

Comment: Hey nice job, how did you manage to merge the tablayouts with the appbarlayout?, in my case, I need to show the tablayout only when a particular option or tab of the bottomnavigationview is pressed, let's say that the tablayout will be displayed only when Collections is pressed, I think each fragment should have its own appbarlayout (with the toolbar).